# How to change the CSS file for the TinyMCE (version 6) on the fly without hard reinitializing?

Tags: css, tinymce, tinymce-6

TinyMCE is often used in the CMS Software. The CSS file, that is currently bound to the TinyMCE editor, needs often to be exchanged.

There are two important things:

- The current CSS file must be cleanly unloaded, otherwise their CSS rules will still affect the contents of the editor.
- If the CSS file has been just changed but its name remains the same, reloading might have no effect because of cache.

Here is the solution:

```js
function reloadCSS()
{
  // remove all previous CSS files
  tinymce.activeEditor.dom.styleSheetLoader.unloadAll(tinymce.activeEditor.contentCSS);
  
  // clean up the variable for storing the list of CSS files
  tinymce.activeEditor.contentCSS = [];

  // add the timestamp to the css to force loading from the server (not from cache)
  let new_css = 'editor.css?t=' + Date.now();

  // add new CSS files to the variable for storing the list of CSS files
  tinymce.activeEditor.contentCSS.push(new_css);
  
  // load new CSS file into the editor
  tinymce.activeEditor.dom.styleSheetLoader.load(new_css);
}
```

I tried to do this first with hard reinitializing but it was not so effective.